# Finding $\lim_{x\to 1 }\left( \frac{x-1-x\ln x }{x(x-1)^{2}}\right)$ without L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would like to calculate this limit but without using L'Hopital's rule

$$\lim_{x\to 1 }\left( \frac{x-1-x\ln(x) }{x(x-1)^{2}}\right)=-\dfrac{1}{2}$$

**My thoughts:**

Note that $\lim\limits_{x\to 1 }\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x-1}=1$ so I tried :

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 1 }\left( \dfrac{x-1-x\ln(x) }{x(x-1)^{2}}\right)&=\lim_{x\to 1 }\left( \dfrac{1}{x(x-1)}-\dfrac{\ln(x)}{(x-1)^2}\right) \\
&=\lim_{x\to 1 }\left( \dfrac{1}{x(x-1)}\right)-\lim_{x\to 1 }\left(\dfrac{1}{(x-1)}\cdot\dfrac{\ln(x)}{(x-1)}\right) 
\end{align*}
but with no luck

Comment: Let $x=1+t$ and use the power series of $\ln(1+t)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let us first make $x=y+1$. So, $$\dfrac{x-1-x\ln(x) }{x(x-1)^{2}}=\frac{y-(y+1) \log (y+1)}{y^2 (y+1)}$$ Now, consider Taylor expansion around $y=0$ $$\log(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ So, the numerator write $$y-(y+1) \log (y+1)=-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{6}+O\left(y^4\right)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Not exactly. Perform the long division.

Comment: To get the limit faster, you can use the fact that $1+y\approx 1$ since $y$ goes to $0$.

Comment: For the limit, it is fine. If you perform the long division, you shoud get $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2 y}{3}+O\left(y^2\right)$

Comment: $\dfrac{2}{3}$ where it comes from instead of $\dfrac{1}{6}$

Comment: $$\frac{y-(y+1) \log (y+1)}{y^2 (y+1)}=\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{6}+o\left(y^3\right) \right) \cdot \left( {1 \over y^2}(1-y+\frac{y^2}{2} + o(y^2))\right)\\
= \left(-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{6}+o\left(y^3\right) \right) \cdot \left( (\dfrac{1}{y^2}-\dfrac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2} + o(1))\right)\\
= \left(-\frac{y^2}{2}+o\left(y^2\right) \right) \cdot \left( (\dfrac{1}{y^2}-\dfrac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{2} + o(1))\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x - 1 - x\log x}{x(x - 1)^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x - 1 - x\log x}{1\cdot(x - 1)^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t - (1 + t)\log (1 + t)}{t^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t - \log (1 + t) - t\log(1 + t)}{t^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t - \log (1 + t)}{t^{2}} - \frac{\log(1 + t)}{t}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{t - \left(t - \dfrac{t^{2}}{2} + o(t^{2})\right)}{t^{2}} - 1\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{2} + o(1)\right) - 1\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2} - 1 = -\frac{1}{2}\notag
\end{align}

Comment: Very Well Explained

Comment: @Educ: Thanks for the compliments. Just wanted to add that Taylor's expansions should  be used together with algebraic simplification and usage of standard limits (like $(1/t)\log(1 + t) \to 1$). It is slightly more difficult to calculate the series for $t - (1 + t)\log(1 + t)$ directly.